# Make zC close only current and nested folds

Tags: folding, filetype-json

How can I make `zC` fold only the current fold and the ones underneath? now it closes all outer folds.

For example, something like this will result in all brackets closing, while I would like to have only `GlossList` and the ones underneath folded.

```
{                                                                               
  "glossary": {                                                               
    "title": "example glossary",                                            
    "GlossDiv": {                                                               
    "title": "S",                                                       
    "GlossList": { <-cursor here                                                            
       "GlossEntry": {                                                 
         "ID": "SGML",                                               
         "SortAs": "SGML",                                                     
         "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",                  
         "Acronym": "SGML",                                                    
         "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",                                            
         "GlossDef": {
           "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
           "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
         },
         "GlossSee": "markup"                                                  
              }                                                               
          }                                                                   
      }                                                                       
  }                                                                           
}
```

Atom's Vim integration works like that, but I can't get used to the editor itself.

Edit:
How vim behaves
[image: zC Vim]

How atom behaves (and I would like to get vim to behave)
[image]

Comment: How about `zc`?

Comment: `zc` only closes the current fold, leaving nested ones open; i.e: if I reopen `GlossList`, `GlossEntry` will also be open.

Comment: How do you reopen GlossList without reopening GlossEntry if they are folded to a single line?

Comment: I have added an example to my post. See that vim closes the entire document, instead of just the current fold.

Answer (score 1):

*Seems that this would have a straightforward answer yet I'm not finding anything **simple** that accomplishes exactly what OP wants. OTOH, I'm not too well versed in folds! Anyways, here are some approximations. Maybe they'll be useful...*

If you know the number of fold levels from the deepest point to the cursor you can do `Nzm` where N is an integer. With your example this would be `3zm`. Open it back up with `3zr` (or `zr` three times) Unfortunately, this starts from the deepest point *in the buffer* and works its way up. IOW it's not related to your cursor position!

An alternative that takes the cursor position into consideration, is to move your cursor to the deepest point of the section you want to fold, as opposed to the top of the section, and repeat `zc` (enter repeatedly or do `Nzc` with appropriate `N`) until you are at the point you are starting in your example.

Note: I'm using syntax folding here `set fdm=syntax` as opposed to `indent` or other method.